# Unable to uninstall an Assembly from GAC?

Tags: .net, assemblies, gac, gacutil

I am unable to uninstall an Assembly (log4net.dll) from GAC. It is giving following error.

**"Assembly is required by one or more applications".**

However if I search the Assembly using ProcessExplorer nothing comes up? How can I remove this Assembly from GAC?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Have you considered reading [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/873195) and trying it out?

> **Warning** Serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly by using Registry Editor or by using another method. These problems might require that you reinstall the operating system. Microsoft cannot guarantee that these problems can be solved. Modify the registry at your own risk.
>
> To work around this problem, examine the list of values for the following subkeys in Registry Editor:
>
> **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Installer\Assemblies\Global**
>   **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\Installer\Assemblies\Global**
>
> If the value for the  entry is a Windows Installer descriptor, delete the  entry. 
>   For example, the value might be a cryptic REG_MULTI_SZ entry that resembles the following:
>   =ysgSC6wx9uiD1dqmmjW>m$!GP^D'A@?z}gn3}lta
>
> **Note** You must delete the  entry. Do not just clear the value of the  entry.

Comment: Thanks!  Worked for me, too.  I also saw it at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alanshi/2003/12/10/why-cant-i-uninstall-my-assembly

Comment: Still works, 10 yrs later. Didn't have the HKCU key, but the one I was trying to get rid of was there under the HKLM path.

Answer (score 7):

The most likely cause of this is that you have installed the log4net assembly via a Windows Installer (msi-package). If that is the case, try to uninstall it using Add/Remove programs.

Answer (score 1):

The following steps helped me to remove `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common,Version=12.0.0,PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91`
from gac

```
cd %systemroot%\assembly\
```

From here you may have more that one "gac" directory, so you will have to search within each to find your component.

```
cd gac_msil
cd <assembly DLL name>
cd <assembly version number>__<public key token>
```

For example: `12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91`

```
erase *.*
```

Say "y" to "are you sure".

```
cd ..
rd <assembly version number>__<public key token>
cd ..
rd <assembly DLL name>
```

Comment: Please check the guide https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, your answer was all faulty because of wrong formatting