# Oracle .Net ManagedDataAccess Error: Could not load type 'OracleInternal.Common.ConfigBaseClass' from assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle, entity-framework

I have a project that works locally, on our dev server, and on our production server.

When I try to run it on the test server, I get the error below, and I don't know what to do about it beyond stare at my screen blankly.  Hints?  Process to trace the issue to its source?

I've installed the NuGet package for Oracle 12.2, etc.

> Could not load type 'OracleInternal.Common.ConfigBaseClass' from
>   assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'.    Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'OracleInternal.Common.ConfigBaseClass' from assembly
>   'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'OracleInternal.Common.ConfigBaseClass' from assembly
>   'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'.]
>   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EntityFrameworkProviderSettings.Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFProviderSettings.IEFProviderSettings.get_TracingEnabled()
>   +0    Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFProviderSettings.InitializeProviderSettings()
>   +111    Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices..ctor()
>   +629    Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices..cctor()
>   +28
>
> [TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices'
>   threw an exception.]
>   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices.get_Instance()
>   +24

The Web.Config has the following blocks in it:

```
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
  </configSections>
```

AND

```
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="PVMDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=pdxcludds108.pacificorp.us)(PORT=11086))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DDS1086.PACIFICORP.US))) " />
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="OracleDbContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=USERID;Password=WORKINGPASSWORD;Data Source=PVMDataSource" />
    <add name="PVMEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.PVMModel.csdl|res://*/Models.PVMModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.PVMModel.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=pdxcludds108.pacificorp.us:11086/DDS1086.PACIFICORP.US;PASSWORD=XXXXXXX;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=XXX&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

NOTE: There are other projects working on this server, they're just using a different version of the Oracle client for .Net.  None of the others is using only the Managed driver.  I am looking for a way to dig into this error, some hint as to where that type is sourced and loaded from.

Comment: How did you install the Oracle libraries?

Comment: My understanding is that with the managed data access you don't need to install the Oracle libraries, the pointer to them is included in the Web.Config.  Editing question to include that information.

Comment: I didn't mean the Oracle client. I meant the Oracle DLL's used by .NET. How did you install those?

Comment: I used the standard NuGet package.  "Official Oracle ODP.NET Managed Entity Framework Driver" and its pal the managed driver.

Comment: Is the IIS application pool on the test server configured to use the same version of the .net framework as in dev and prod?  That's a common culprit for these type of things.

Comment: Same .net framework, both servers.

Comment: I have the same problem but everything was working fine until I actually installed the full Oracle 12 Database on the same box.

Answer (score 29):

There is a conflict between `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` from NuGet and the one that is installed (by Oracle client installation) on a server and that is registered in GAC.

Unregister `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` from GAC and you will get rid of the error: Run command line and navigate to the directory:

> *{Oracle home}*\product\{version}\client_64\ODP.NET\managed\x64

There you should find `OraProvCfg.exe` file. Run the following command to unregister `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` from GAC:

```
OraProvCfg /action:ungac /providerPath:Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
```

Comment: Is there documentation available from Oracle that explains the issue?

Comment: @youzer Not any I am aware of.

Comment: Along with many others, I agree Oracle's versioning is the real culprit here.  That said, the NuGet package's README file _does_ state explicitly `1. Un-GAC and un-configure any existing assembly (i.e. Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll) and policy DLL 
(i.e. Policy.4.121.Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll) for the ODP.NET, Managed Driver ...` (for version 12.1.0.2 at least).  The answer by @Jan has worked for me on several occasions, BTW.

Comment: I just get `Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  Oracle Providers for .NET Configuration Utility for .NET Framework 4 : Release 4.121.2.0 ....` with a Copyright and Usage info.

Answer (score 23):

You have to **remove** the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess assembly in your **GAC** (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly...)

> Use the command tool `gacutil` to remove the assembly:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\YOUR_VERSION\bin\NETFX
> 4.6.1 Tools> gacutil /u Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Comment: This fails for me because it says Windows Installer is using it.

Comment: So actually, I found this that helped me, in case anyone needs it because they also had the same error about Windows Installer being a dependency:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447306/unable-to-uninstall-an-assembly-from-gac/2447331#comment85083341_2447331  Basically, go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Installer\Assemblies\Global` and  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\Installer\Assemblies\Global` and remove the assembly from there, then you can do the `gacutil -u` command.  I didn't have to go to the HKCU location - nothing there - but it was at the HKLM location.

Comment: Then I uninstalled and re-installed the Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio after I did that.

Comment: This answer solved my problem too. Open cmd as Administrator, cd to the folder and run "gacutil.exe /u Oracle.ManagedDataAccess". It should work.

Answer (score 8):

Was able to fix it by replacing references in the project to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework from those installed by the package manager to those installed by the oracle client installer. The versions are the same but the build number is different on those DLLs

Comment: So you say the NuGet package is unusable? Why use it then? Why does it exist at all? Is it a trap? I don't have an Oracle client on my dev machine and the NuGet package works fine. When deploying the app to a machine that has Oracle server installed, it breaks with this error.

Comment: Yes, Oracle did it again - they released the same version of the DLL (first 3 numbers are exactly the same) and change implementation without backward compatibility. They did it in the past (about 5 years ago) so no surprise for me. I do use Nuget package though and then on the destination server I make sure to **remove** Oracle.ManagedDataAccess dll from the GAC. This way it will start using the local (/bin) copy of the DLL. You have to be careful with this approach though if you have other applications on the server that use the same DLL and rely on the fact that it exists in the GAC.

Comment: A support person from Oracle recommended doing the same, and future releases should not put the assembly in the GAC anymore. But for now, I have to remove it manually. Without gacutil.exe on a non-dev machine, how should I do that?

Comment: Copy the gacutil to your server or just find the DLLs in the .NET/ver/assembly directory and delete them.

Answer (score 6):

As others said you need to remove Oracle.ManagedDataAccess from GAC.

I run `{Oracle home}\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\ODP.NET\managed\x64\unconfigure.bat` and `{Oracle home}\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\ODP.NET\managed\x836\unconfigure.bat`  and it worked

Answer (score 3):

We had the exact same problem as Dylan above. The issue appears to be with that specific Oracle version (4.121.2.0).

The solution was simple: Just go into Nuget and move up to the next version of your Nuget package for the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client, 4.122.1.0.

Once we did that we could have mixed Oracle client or no-client environments or servers with or without the GAC Oracle installed, keep older apps that still use the GAC, and add new projects that use the Nuget packages. Its always a bad idea in these blogs to ask people to uninstall legacy stuff - like remove the Oracle dll in the GAC on a server - when you have environments with many legacy dependancies that still might reference it.

Comment: Seems like a bug that was resolved in the intervening 4 years. Good on Oracle.

Comment: Updating to the right NuGet version resolved this without having to unregister anything in the GAC.

Answer (score 2):

If removing the DLL from the GAC is not an option, consider getting the next version of oracle.managedData.access 12.2.1 and just put them on the server in the bin directory.
Afterwards you need to add an assemblyBinding to your web.config file.

This way you get arround pulling the 12.1.2 version from the GAC during runtime that will case the error.
You do not need to recompile your app against the new version.

```html
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.1.2.0" newVersion="12.2.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely something weird with this issue. I was developing an app on my local server which ran fine but got this error when I uploaded the app to our server. The server has oracle client installed. After looking at this thread I copied the two DLLs (`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll` & `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.dll`) from within oracle client and replaced the versions in my app bin directory. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my scenario, i have a console application consuming a class library database utility.
I had to reference the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess also on the console application so it can find the dll on runtime.
I don't know if this is the best approach, but worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

good afternoon

I want to share how I solved this same error:

1. I started by starting visual studio 2019 cmd as administrator.
2. I ran the following command line in cmd: gacutil -u Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Basically this command line will remove the Oracle reference from the GAC (Global Assembly Cache), this way it will only get the reference from the package that is in the project (which nuget installs) and not from the oracle client.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the Oracle Client drivers. The .NET packages don't contain them; they provide a translation from the managed world to the unmanaged. The drivers are in the unmanaged world and need to be installed properly.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, but does that mean that I need to dig into TNS issues as well as driver version issues?

Comment: TNS is one way that the driver finds out how to connect to what you want it to, yes.

Comment: I'd like to call this an answer, but it doesn't actually solve anything.  There are other projects on the server using Oracle connections, just not solely the managed one.  How do I debug this issue?  Where do I dig?

Comment: I think this is wrong...  There are 2 .NET data access packages.  The managed and unmanaged packages (yeah, awesome naming).  The "unmanaged" .NET libraries are .net libraries that interop with native Oracle.  The managed .NET libraries are pure managed code hitting Oracle directly and saving you the need to install Oracle client on the executing machine.  The fact that I'm here commenting on THIS thread says that it's not smooth sailing...