# Visual studio 2013 stops working after removing Oracle.ManagedDataAccess assembly

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6, oracle-manageddataaccess

I am facing the same problem in this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407213/oracle-net-manageddataaccess-error-could-not-load-type-oracleinternal-common)

I tried to unregister the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess assembly as told in one of the answers...

> You have to remove the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess assembly in your GAC
>   (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly...)
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\YOUR_VERSION\bin\NETFX
>   4.6.1 Tools> gacutil /u Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Now, every time I try to perform *update-database* command in package manager console, the visual studio stops working.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

The problem was the version os DLL in "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config".
The version of the entry "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" was set for a version different (prior) from the nuget package that I installed.